# Doc bug? Instructions for automake don't work for me

Tags: configure, automake

The instruction on the automake man page and the online manual at [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/autoconf-Invocation.html) don't work for me.

They say that a bare "automake" reads configure.am and writes configure.  However, when I try it there's no error, but nothing is written to configure.  I have to use

```
automake configure.am >configure
```

Is this a doc bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The title of the page you linked says: `Using autoconf to Create configure` and you are using `automake`...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the file is called `configure.ac`, not `configure.am`.

Secondly, just run `autoreconf` to generate `configure`. Depending on the files present, it will call `automake`, `autoconf`, `aclocal`, etc. pp. in the correct sequence.